# Jquery: On keyup event to add elements to Datalist for autocomplete

Tags: jquery, html, autocomplete

I am trying to make an autocomplete text input box.
The problem is that the text box does not even register my "Enter" keypress.

The whole idea is that, as soon as enter is pressed, the value of the input field needs to be added as an `<option>` in the `<datalist>`, so the next time it can suggest a previously input value.

This is my code: For some reason even an enter is not registered in the input box.

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>
        Color Picker:
    </p>
    <form action="">
        <input id="auto-list" type="text" list="dlist">
        <datalist id="dlist">
            <option id="0" value="awesome" label="cool"></option>
            <option id="1" value="hot" label="fire"></option>
        </datalist>
        </input>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

test.js

```
//Autocomplete test
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#auto-list").keyup(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            alert('enter!');
            var $text_val = this.value;
            var $id_to_assign = "id_" + $text_val;
            if(this.find($($id_to_assign))) {
                alert("already seen this shiz..");
            }
            $("dlist").append("<option id=" + $id_to_assign + " value=" + $text_val + " label='auto-added'></option>");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code is working well when I test it here. Are you sure that test.js is alongside your index.html?

Comment: working? how? I mean is the autofill from the browser?
Basically, it will display the default `options` like awesome etc. but will take new ones. Also it does not shout the alert on enter key in the first place.

Comment: If I type a new item and press enter, it ends up in the list -- I can select it from the drop-down. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: So to check if your browser is doing this for you, check if the autofill item has both the value and a grayed out text on the right like `awesome` has `cool`

Comment: The problem comes from the form being submitted on pressing enter -- if I comment out the surrounding form, you get the expected behaviour. I'm having a little trouble preventing the form from submitting though -- `event.preventDefault()` doesn't appear to stop the form submission :/

Comment: Hey @daf, thanks for your help! I found the problem.. I was supposed to catch the `keydown` then do the `event.preventDefault()` on that and place my `keyup` query inside that... It works now.. I still might have a question about adding to the list..